# How to combine separate strings into one in Oracle?

Tags: string, oracle, concatenation

I have a list of strings. For exmaple,

```
'up', 'down', 'left', 'right'
```

I need to combine these separate strings into one string, with their commas. Like this

```
'up, down, left, right'
```

Does anyone have any ideas how to do this in Oracle?

Comment: every string is a row or are separated fields?

Comment: They are not rows. They are individual values that come this way from an SSRS report. They user checks off multiple option from a drop down and then they are sent to sql like on first example, as separate strings, separated with commas. Think of it as `select 'up', 'down', 'left', 'right' from dual`

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate, it is different.

Answer (score 0):

[CONCAT OPERATOR](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/operators003.htm) is `||`

```
 select 'up' || ','  || 'down' ||  ','  ||  'left' ','  ||  'right' 
 from dual
```

Comment: Is there a function that will do this? Such as `MakeIntoOneString('up', 'down', 'left', 'right')` ? The way I'm getting the strings this would be the best way for me.

Comment: Can you give me a reason why using `||` doesnt work for you. Maybe if i understand the context can help you better

Comment: If you have it as fields you use `||` if you have it like rows you use https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/string-aggregation-techniques